# Popoto.js create new graph from cypher-query

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, neo4j, cypher

I would like to know if there is a method to create a graph based on a cipher-query or create a scheme based on a cipher-query that was sent via the rest.post method. I can't find anything that works in the existing functions.

A sample query would be like: `MATCH (n)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(m) WHERE m.name contains "ger" RETURN n,m LIMIT 20`